# Changing mixin behavior based on & element type

Tags: css, less, mixins

Is there any way to check referenced element type inside a mixin?

Something like

```
.mymixin(&) when (& = 'a') {}
.mymixin(&) when (& = 'li') {}
.mymixin(&) when (& = 'div') {}
```

Comment: You can pass the element type as a parameter to the mixin and use guards but I don't think you can use `&`.

Comment: Idea is to autodetect element type inside a mixin anyhow. To reduce some filesize. 

Imagine we need to do anything like 

.list .social a,
.list .social-another a i {
  .mixin(); that prints &.short { color:#fff } if elements is "a", and &.long { color:#fff } if element is "i"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign the value of the & parent reference to a variable and neither use it as a argument for mixins.

You can use [mixins guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) or [pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching)

Also check [CSS guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) which enable you to use:

```
& when (@my-option = true) {
  button {
    color: white;
  }
  a {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```